# com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: The document has no catalog object (meaning: it's an invalid PDF)

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am working with itext 5.5.13.

My code read a pdf file, writes a text on the first page and saves the new file :

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ReadPdf);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(NewPdf);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fos);

PdfContentByte under = stamper.getOverContent(1);

Font font = FontFactory.getFont(strFontFace, size, weight);
font.setColor(new BaseColor(nColorRed, nColorGreen, nColorBlue));
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(TESTO, font);
Phrase p = new Phrase(chunk);
PdfPTable datatable = new PdfPTable(1);
datatable.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
datatable.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
datatable.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidth(nBorderWidth);
datatable.getDefaultCell().setBorderColor(new BaseColor(nBorderColorRed, nBorderColorGreen, nBorderColorBlue));
datatable.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(nHeight);
datatable.getDefaultCell().setRotation(90);
datatable.addCell(p);
datatable.setTotalWidth(nWidth);
datatable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, rectangle.getLeft() + nPosx, rectangle.getBottom() + (height - nPosy), under);

stamper.flush();
fos.flush();
stamper.close();
fos.close();
reader.close();
```

The method is not error but when I go to read the "**NewPdf**" file gives me the 
error in question.Even Acrobat can not open it anymore.
This same method works for many other files, what is the problem for this file?

The file I read has no problems and I have no exceptions when I read it with PdfReader and Acrobat open it without problems.

**Below the info taken by PdfReader :**

> Number of pages: 2
>  Size of page 1: [0.0,0.0,593.0,840.0]
>   Rotation of page 1: 0
>  Page size with rotation of page 1:
>   Rectangle: 593.0x840.0 (rot: 0 degrees)
>  Size of page 1:
>   [0.0,0.0,510.0,676.0]
>  Rotation of page 1: 0
>  Page size with
>   rotation of page 2: Rectangle: 510.0x676.0 (rot: 0 degrees)
>
> Is rebuilt? false
>  Is encrypted? false
>  Is appendable? false
>   Is FullPermissions? true
>  Is 128Key? false
>  Is HybridXref?
>   false
>  Is MetadataEncrypted? false
>  Is NewXrefType? false
>  Is
>   Tagged? false
>  Is Tampered? false

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: No PDF = no answer. You say your code works with many documents except one. Share that one PDF.

Comment: the pdf contains sensitive data otherwise they are already shared.If the controls on the file, however, do not indicate problems with writing and the code to write a chunk is correct, why after writing invalidate the pdf?

Comment: iText is open source if you use it in an open source context. If you work in a closed source context, you are required to purchase a commercial license. If you purchase a license, you can share the PDF privately under an NDA. That's the professional thing to do. I repeat: no PDF = no answer! No one can reproduce your problem without the PDF.

Comment: I have to second Bruno: code "usually working but not for this file" generally require that special PDF to analyse the issue.

Comment: As a side-note, please read the formatting guidelines. You do not need to add `<br>` to your code.